# Where is Derby database stored when I create it from Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

Where is Derby database stored when I create it from netbeans?
How Can I combine it with the rest of my project in one folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-Click on `Databases->JavaDB` in the `Service` View and select `Properties...`

[image]

This will open the following screen, where the location is visible and could be changed:
[image]